# Solving this ambiguous type issue without resorting to Proxy

Tags: haskell

I have the following type-class:

```
class MapsTo k v m where
    innerMap :: m -> Map k v
```

If I declare the following function signature:

```
keys :: MapsTo k v m => m -> [k]
```

I get the following error:

```
Could not deduce (MapsTo k v0 m)
  from the context: MapsTo k v m
    bound by the type signature for:
               keys :: forall k v m. MapsTo k v m => m -> [k]
```

Which makes sense since `v` is not used anywhere as type parameter.

Since I think using `AllowAmbiguousTypes` is not a good idea, I resorted to `Data.Proxy`:

```
keys :: MapsTo k v m => Proxy v -> m -> [k]
```

This works, but I'm wondering if there's a way to solve this without resorting to `Proxy`.

Note that for my problem at hand, any two combination of `k`, `v`, or `m` does not uniquely determine the remaining type. So sadly, using functional dependencies won't help in my case.

Comment: Is `v` always uniquely defined by `k` and `m`? If so, [`FunctionalDependencies`](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functional_dependencies) is what you want. Otherwise, it's not possible.

Comment: No, in my case I might have `(MapsTo String Bool, MapsTo String Int)`.

Comment: Then it is not possible, sorry.

Comment: Sure it is, if you don't like an extra `Proxy v` parameter then you can still pass a `v` parameter... It just isn't very elegant.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson, that seems rather old-fashioned these days, and makes it hard to see that everything is okay.

Comment: @DamianNadales Just to push back a bit: the evidence you give ("I have `MapsTo String Bool` and `MapsTo String Int`", N.B. these do not even have kind `Constraint`, but `* -> Constraint`) does not support the conclusion you draw ("`k` and `m` do not uniquely define `v`"). Are you *sure* that functional dependencies will not help?

Comment: Thanks for pushing back :) Sorry, I meant `MapsTo String Bool mm` and `MapsTo String Bool Int mm` for the same `mm`. So in this case `k` and `m` do not determine `v`, do they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you really need to pass a type as an argument, you basically have four options, two standard and two GHC-specific:

#### Standard options

As you've recognized, you can use `proxy` arguments, typically instantiated to `Proxy`:

```
keys :: MapsTo k v m => proxy v -> m -> [k]
```

The caller may (but need not) call this with a `Proxy` value; if they have another type on hand with the right structure, that will do as well.

The other standard option is to use either `Const` or its flipped cousin `Tagged`, which was designed for this purpose:

```
import Data.Tagged

-- Either
keys :: MapsTo k v m => Tagged v (m -> [k])
-- or
keys :: MapsTo k v m => m -> Tagged v [k]
```

#### GHC-specific options

You're unlikely to want it, but `GHC.Exts` offers a type `Proxy#`, which is a sort of proxy that's never actually passed at runtime, so it shouldn't have any performance cost.

```
keys :: MapsTo k v m => Proxy# v -> m -> [k]
-- called like this:
keys (proxy# :: Proxy# Int) m
```

Whereas it was once mostly useless, `AllowAmbiguousTypes` is now valuable in combination with `TypeApplications` and `ScopedTypeVariables`. You can write

```
keys :: forall v m k. MapsTo k v m => m -> [k]

:t keys @Int
keys @Int :: MapsTo k Int m => m -> [k]
```

Comment: I found the last option (`AllowAmbiguousTypes` + `TypeApplications` + `ScopedTypeVariables`) to be the more elegant one.

Answer (score 2):

The dependency between `k`, `v`, `m` might be described functionally by an additional parameter. For example, let's call it `f` for "field", and assume that `f` and `k` determine `v`:

```
class MapsTo f k v m | f k -> v where
  innerMap :: m -> Map k v

keys :: forall f k v m. MapsTo f k v m => m -> [k]
```

Then you can apply `keys` to `f` instead of `v`, which can sometimes be more elegant, e.g., when `f` is just a symbol and `v` is a complex type that you'd rather not spell out.

```
keys @f :: m -> [k]  -- v determined by f and k
```